# How can I convert a high frequency sine signal to a square wave?

Tags: transistors, rf, analog, power-amplifier

I'm trying to convert a high frequency sine wave signal (approximately 130 MHz) with lets say 3 Vpp into a square wave signal (also 130 MHz) with 0V and 5Vp. The square wave is subsequently used as a control signal to switch a MOSFET, which will be part of a switching amplifier I am developing.

I was thinking it might be possible with a Schmitt trigger, but I am not sure if this will work.

Does anyone have an idea or encountered a similar problem or can help?

Edit: Changed Switching amplifier to MOSFET

Comment: Can you post a schematic?

Comment: You can get help from these threads.  https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/high-speed-sine-wave-to-square-wave-converter.45041/    https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339468/sine-to-square-wave-high-frequency

Comment: I'm more concerned what you think you're going to switch at 130MHz? o_o

Comment: A Schmitt trigger is possible, but may or may not be called-for depending on where the sine is coming from, how noisy it is, and how much noise you need to eliminate from the signal. Such a trigger may cost more and/or be trickier to design for high speed than a simpler solution. You also may need to consider phase shift: how much can you tolerate? A trigger will introduce delay.

Comment: Is the input on a DC rail or is it 3Vpp about 0?

Comment: @name_n I think TimW's comment is an important one. One doesn't just pop in some standard saws-all module that converts a sine to a square wave ... especially not at 130 MHz anyway ... without knowing what's driving it and knowing it it drives and having quantitative specs. I could suggest, for example, looking at anything from TI's [THS3491](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ths3491.pdf) to TI's [BUF634A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/buf634a.pdf) and still have no idea if they might be applicable. I'd just be throwing mud against the wall to see what sticks. Write something more?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to convert a high frequency sine wave signal (approximately 130 MHz) with lets say 3 Vpp into a square wave signal (also 130 MHz) with 0V and 5Vp.

You can employ a straightforward approach using a high-speed comparator, such as the LTC6752, to convert a sine wave into a square wave. While this wave isn't perfect and may not be in phase, it's notably uncomplicated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is going to be getting a nice square out of the other end.

Don't forget that a 'square' wave actually has finite rise and fall times.

Check with your switching amplifier specification what rise and fall times it can tolerate on its 'switching' input. You may find that you can simply amplify and shift your sine wave to swing between 0 and 5 V, and it will work.

If the edge rate is not quite fast enough from that, then an option nearly as straightforward is to amplify the sinewave a bit more, and clamp it to 0 V and 5 V.

If you need faster edges, then an excellent solution can be to use a 'universal' input clock buffer, these are usually CML. An LVDS receiver to logic output could also be pressed into service.